# How to handle the dummy variables with overlapping categories?

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, ranking, many-categories

**Background of The Question**

Let's say, I have four categories (A, B, C, D). Considering one (D) as a reference variable, there will be three categories on which I have to work. But the problem is one participant can be in several categories, in each observation. For example: In a single observation, a participant can be in both A and C categories which violates the rules of creating dummy variables as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30818/dummy-variables-with-overlapping-categories#108838).

**Then, My Question**

Which type of variables (like dummy variable) can I use that will allow me to keep a participant in two or more categories, for a single observation?

**Notes**

- I am aware of [interaction variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104276/multiple-regression-with-overlapping-categorical-dummy-variables#104281). None of the categories (in
  my problem) can be that type of variable.
- I know in CV, there are lots of questions regarding dummy variables. However, I did not find the answer of my question. Instead, I have mostly learned from those questions what should and what should not be done in case of dummy variables.
- My question is similar to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388438/how-to-code-a-categorical-variable-for-logistic-regression-with-overlap-in-the-c) which is unanswered.

Comment: If you are okay with other encoding strategies, you may use Base-N Encoding (I'd prefer it in such a case). Or you may try with Binary Encoding and/or Hash Encoding.

Comment: @AnantKumar Thanks for your response. Can you please answer with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for **Base-N Encoding** using **Python**. Please view the below example data :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','b','c','d','e','ab','bc','bd']})
```

When **Base N Encoder** is applied

```
import category_encoders as ce
encoder= ce.BaseNEncoder(cols=['A'],return_df=True,base=5)
data=encoder.fit_transform(df)
data.loc[:,"A"]=df.A
```

**Base-N Encoder Data Output**

```
    A_0 A_1 A_2 A
0   0   0   1   a
1   0   0   2   b
2   0   0   3   c
3   0   0   4   d
4   0   1   0   e
5   0   1   1   ab
6   0   1   2   bc
7   0   1   3   bd
```

**Binary Encoder Strategy**

```
encoder= ce.BinaryEncoder(cols=['A'],return_df=True)
data=encoder.fit_transform(df)
data.loc[:,"A"]=df.A
```

**Binary Encoder Data Output**

```
    A_0 A_1 A_2 A_3 A
0   0   0   0   1   a
1   0   0   1   0   b
2   0   0   1   1   c
3   0   1   0   0   d
4   0   1   0   1   e
5   0   1   1   0   ab
6   0   1   1   1   bc
7   1   0   0   0   bd
```